# C++ unique_ptr to array element

Tags: c++, arrays, unique-ptr

I had a function that returns a unique_ptr to an array element, and I noticed the original variable was not getting updated.

Why does this work (a[5] == 6 after):

```
int a[10];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    a[i] = i;
}

int* ap = &a[5];

*ap += 1;
```

But

```
int a[10];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    a[i] = i;
}

unique_ptr<int> ap = make_unique<int>(a[5]);

*ap += 1;
```

Does not update the original array element? (a[5] == 5 ):

Comment: Read what [make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) does. It doesn't create a pointer to an existing element, it creates a pointer to a new element initialized with whatever you pass in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [`std::make_unique<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) *constructs a new object*.

Quoting:

> *Constructs* an object of type T and wraps it in a std::unique_ptr.

Therefore, your statement

```
unique_ptr<int> ap = make_unique<int>(a[5]);
```

creates *another* integer (`T = int`) and initializes it with the value of the expression `a[5]`.

So, when you operate on the pointer `ap` you are actually modifying another integer (a *copy* of `a[5]`).

Comment: Ah, of course, thank you. Guess I don't need a unique_ptr there at all anyway, as I don't have to delete that pointer.